# compilation error using zedboard

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, xilinx, petalinux

I had created a project in `Xilinx SDK` using Linux as OS. the code is written in c++ and when I created the project and copied the .elf file of the project to SD card and inserted the SD card into the Zedboard along with other boot files required for booting SD card on Zedboard, I got these error while compiling. I guess the problem is with the compiler because when building the project the compiler in `Xilinx SDK` was "`Xilinx ARM/GNU Linux toolchain`" and I guess the compiler in the preinstalled Petalinux on Zedboard is different. The error which I received is

> zynq> /mnt/mibr.elf
>   /mnt/mibr.elf: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux-armhf.so.3: cannot                                                                                         open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can somebody guide me what should I do to remove this error and make it able to get executed.

Comment: Do you mean while booting...? clearly it compiled if you put it onto an SD card...

Comment: I mean when I try to run the executable(.elf) from Zedboard when i not able to run it and i get the error as given above. The zedboard boots and  I enter in the zynq> command mode,  after that i try to run the .elf which is in SD card, i get the above error. I never had this kind of error when my code was in C. so i guess the problem is due to C++ or the wrong toolchain used when compiling the code in xilinx SDK.

Comment: Are you using the default linux OS that xilinx gave you or have you used petalinux tools or something else to customize it?

Comment: yes, the default Linux OS.

Comment: i actually don't think it's a full toolchain error, I just think that the shared library probably has a different name (or in a worse case it doesn't exist) in your rootfs.